# I have a west highland terrier that is 11yrs old(in human yrs) and he drinks his own urine, what should I do?

Tags: dogs, health, urination

My Westie is 11yrs old and he’s drinking his own urine and I don’t know what I should do.
I give him water throughout the day but he always drinks so much like as if he hasn’t had water in days, he’ll gobble an ice down like as if he was eating a fresh piece of meat.
He would pee in the house just to drink it.
He’s been taken to the vet and tested if he had UTI but he doesn’t.
If anyone has any suggestions plz let me know.

Comment: The excessive drinking of water might indicate diabetes, you should get his blood glucose level tested after he ate his food. If he peed inside the house, licking up his urine might be his way of keeping the house clean. Tell the vet **all** of the symptoms you listed here. The main problem is not his drinking of urine, but his excessive drinking of any liquid.